# Are autism and schizophrenia more severe in Sub-Saharan populations?

Tags: evolution, autism, evolutionary-psychology, genetics, schizophrenia

Some time ago, I read a Spanish news article discussing the creation of Neanderthal proto-brains using CRISPR. I have translated the relevant part:

> Interestingly, some characteristics of Neanderthal brains resemble those of humans with autism, according to Muotri. 'I don’t want families to think that I am comparing autistic children with Neanderthals, but it is an important observation,' the researcher said. 'In modern humans, these kinds of changes are linked to defects in brain development necessary for socialization. If we believe that this is one of our advantages over Neanderthals, it's something significant.'

Source: [genotipia.com](https://genotipia.com/minicerebros-neandertal/)

I told myself: wait, *all* Neanderthal were autistic? Maybe autism was inherited from Neanderthal? But soon I searched if autism is present in Sub-Saharan people with no Neanderthal or Denisovian DNA and of course autism is also a Sapiens issue.

Recently I returned to focus my attention on the topic and I started to read a bit more. I read another statement in a different Spanish news source:

> Autism and schizophrenia are uniquely human characteristics.

Source: [lavozdegalicia.es](https://www.lavozdegalicia.es/noticia/firmas/2014/04/18/hallan-cambios-geneticos-separan-sapiens-neandertal/0003_201404G18P26995.htm)

I'm not sure if 'humans' in this context includes other species or refers only to Homo Sapiens. However, what seems clear is that these disorders originate with human emotions and are not present in animals, unless for induced autism in rats using Sodium Valproate I believe.

Regarding [Theory of Mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_mind), I read in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0920996499001012) both spectrums are associated with low ToM. And I have read genes related to autism and schizophrenia are from the same family. The DSM-V indicates they are both spectrums, but neurologically they could represent a single entity.

I have also read that Neanderthal genes reduced the affinity for schizophrenia in Sapiens:

> The study also reveals the discovery of a Neanderthal allele of a gene called ADMTSL3 that reduces the risk of schizophrenia, but influences height. "Our results show that the causal mutation was inherited from Neanderthals," states McCoy.

Source: [agenciasinc.es](https://www.agenciasinc.es/Noticias/Que-aporto-el-ADN-neandertal-a-los-genes-humanos).

So, my theory to be refuted is that, when these genes mixed with Sapiens, they might have produced two outcomes:

- More functional autism and Asperger in autistic Sapiens.
- Less severe and/or less frequent schizophrenia in Sapiens.

If correct, this could be associated with the fact that 200,000 years of Neanderthal existence might have resulted in more stable genes for processing Neanderthal emotions, genes from which Homo Sapiens potentially benefited.

My theory would imply:

- Autism in Sub-Saharan people is more severe.
- Schizophrenia in Sub-Saharan people is more frequent and severe.

Has there been any study about this using [PANSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_Negative_Syndrome_Scale), [PAUSS](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32703733/) or other index that could potentially refute my theory?

<sub>*Original english speach corrected using GPT-4, an OpenAI product.</sub>

Comment: I found a study that matches with this: [First, in four independent case-control datasets totaling 9362 individuals, individuals with schizophrenia had less Neanderthal-derived genetic variation than controls (p=0.044). Second, in 49 unmedicated inpatients with schizophrenia, having more Neanderthal admixture predicted less severe positive symptoms (p=0.046)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8454493/)

Comment: This is not a paper but also matches for less Asperger in Sub-Saharan populations: [Among children of women who were born in sub-Saharan Africa only 1 case of Asperger's was recorded, but the risk for the more classical form of autism (the more well-known form that is associated with lower intelligence) was found to be relatively high with 11 cases found. Among Europeans, in contrary, Asperger's and autism were much more evenly spread.](https://spaceandai.com/project/could-aspergers-really-be-a-legacy-of-the-neanderthals-2/)